# Adding Asp.Net MVC 4 to an Asp.Net Webforms 4.5 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webforms

I have tried to follow these instructions to add Asp.Net MVC 4 to an Asp.Net Webforms 4.5 web application:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

The difference is that the article covers adding Asp.Net MVC 3 to an Asp.Net Webforms 4.0 application.

To get the application to build I also had to add the following nuget packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Along with any dependencies these packages have. (I assume these were needed due to some new stuff in the asp.net mvc 4 template, such as bundling and Web Api.)

When running the application I can access my webforms default.aspx page. But when trying to access the mvc route /Home/Index/ I get the following yellow screen of death:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'BeginContext' does not exist in the current context
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 50:             #line default
>   Line 51:             #line hidden
>   Line 52: BeginContext("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", 39, 2, true);
>   Line 53: 
>   Line 54: WriteLiteral("\r\n");
>
> Source File: c:\Users\deap\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4e75f435\a63aa726\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.m4g9z3sv.0.cs    Line: 52

Does anyone have any idea what's going on and what I need to do to get it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights sleep I decided to compare my web.config with the dummy mvc web application I copied folders from.

Changing the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

into:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

solved my problem.